# Tournament Plotting: Who is good against whom?

Tags: r, data-visualization, python, networks

I would like to get insight into who is good against whom. Imagine a tournament setting* of 40 contestants and you're interested in seeing who is good against who in the top 10: how could we make this insightful using graphics?

I'd mostly be interested in just finding out a good (best) method, though I'm also open to specific R/Python/Other software/package suggestions to accomplish it.

The hidden goal would be that you might even see clusters forming of playing styles as some players are good against some others, while their style might be good against yet another group of players!

* All contestants play games against each other and the winner is known

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have all the pairwise win-rates? Then perhaps plot then in a grid, with colors indicating win-rate. An implementation in python:

```
from itertools import product

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

np.random.seed(34563)

# Create win_rates. Symmetric with .5's down the diagonal
win_rates = np.random.uniform(size=(10, 10))
for i, j in product(range(10), repeat=2):
    if i == j:
        win_rates[i, j] = .5
    if i > j:
        win_rates[i, j] = 1 - win_rates[j, i]

def plot_heatmap(win_rates):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.imshow(win_rates, cmap=cm.bwr_r, interpolation='none')
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.bwr_r)
    m.set_array(win_rates)
    fig.colorbar(m)

    return fig
```

---

A natural ordering is simply by placement in the tournament. First let's try by overall win rate, here assuming that everyone plays an equal amount of games against everyone else.

```
overall_win_rates = np.mean(win_rates, axis=1)
sorted_indexes = np.argsort(-overall_win_rates)
win_rates = win_rates[sorted_indexes]    # Sort rows
win_rates = win_rates[:, sorted_indexes] # Sort columns
overall_win_rates = overall_win_rates[sorted_indexes]

fig = plot_heatmap(win_rates)
```

[image: Sorted by overall win rate]

---

Clustering could also be used to order the contestants. Input the matrix of win-rates into some clustering algorithm (see [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) for a variety of them in Python) and put people in the same group next to each other in the ordering. This will cluster people based on their win-rates versus particular people, which is how I would hope to extract some semblance of playing styles. Combine that ordering with a plot like the one above.

This is an example using [affinity propagation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation). I'm actually not very familiar with this algorithm, but it's one of the few that doesn't have the number of clusters as a parameter, which is nice for the application.

```
from sklearn import cluster
ap = cluster.AffinityPropagation()
clusters = ap.fit_predict(win_rates)

sorted_indexes = np.lexsort([-overall_win_rates, clusters])
win_rates = win_rates[sorted_indexes]
win_rates = win_rates[:, sorted_indexes]
overall_win_rates = overall_win_rates[sorted_indexes]

fig = plot_heatmap(win_rates)
```

[image]

Here, the top rows are a cluster, the next three are a cluster, and the last four are a cluster. Though keep in mind that this is just using the defaults provided, in practice you probably would want to tune the clustering parameters.

Within clusters the rows are sorted by overall win rate. One of several improvements you could make to this figure is an extra column or some way to show overall win rate on the figure, and possibly an indicator for clusters as well.

Comment: The question appears to ask for comparisons between all 40 players and the "top 10." This requires a plausible definition of who those top 10 are and then a visualization of the comparison.  Would you be able to improve this answer to clarify how your proposal is applicable in such a setting, especially where interest might focus on finding the kinds of "clusters" referred to in the question?

Comment: I'm assuming that the top 10 is known and that the question is asking for ways to visualize the win-rates of those in that group. If you can't determine the top 10 in a tournament setting then I wonder what kind of tournament you're running. Clustering is one part of the question, but I don't even think it's the primary part. To me, the main question is: "how could we make this insightful using graphics?"

Comment: You might want to look into the literature on voting systems and voting paradoxes for some insight into why who is in the top $k$ of a tournament might not be so clear. If your focus is on insightful display--which indeed any answer to this question should be--then consider the opportunities afforded by permuting the rows and columns of your matrix: that will elevate it from a mere color-coded lookup table into something that immediately informs the viewer.

Comment: To clarify, yes, the clusters will give some guidance to what characteristics work against specific groups, and this is my main goal. This is very helpful, I did not realize a simple heatmap (though combined with the ordering of clusters) would indeed do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you would add the clustering part, you'd have an amazing answer!

Comment: @PascalvKooten I updated the answer with some sorted examples. It's not the most elucidating with randomly generated data, but I hope it can help.

Comment: @RogerFan It certainly did! I added col/row labels myself, which really helps when it is not random. And indeed, though it is not very clear on the random data, you can still see clusters (at least we know it works). I very much like this approach and I do recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using a fluctuation diagram over a heatmap. Here is an example:
[image]

Fluctuation diagrams use area to represent count, instead of color, which is higher on Cleveland's hierarchy of visual skills.

Sort the players by number of wins, both vertically and horizontally.

It is also possible to include some indicators of confidence in the counts, by using a fluctuation diagram. In the plot above, a permutation test was done to determine if the actual count was around about the expected value, given the marginal frequency (eg how often times the player wins regardless who the opponent is), or above or below.

In the plot above, solid grey boxes indicate the actual count. The grey outline indicates expected count, if both variables were independent (you would use if both players had equal chance of being selected). Boxes are recolored if they are significantly bigger or smaller than the expected count.

Oh, plot was computed using R. If anyone wants the code I can send it.

Comment: (+1) Nice plot!

Comment: Very nice and concise. The visualization of uncertainty could certainly be useful for others, but in my case it is not much needed. How would you address the forming of clusters in this situation? Important findings are more "visual", but it is still hard to find clusters (e.g. if #1, #10 and #15 are good against #3,4,5, they wouldn't be nicely bundled together)

Comment: You can sort by using a clustering algorithm, as an alternative to sorting by magnitude. You first need to define what you mean by similar, is it the proportion of times won, the success against particular players, ... clustering can be so tempting, giving an illusory sense of security but very hard to define.

Comment: The purpose of the above plot was to explore associations between two categorical variables, to find associations that were more or less than expected, not clustering. For clustering I would (1) filter the records so that categories with low overall counts were ignored (2) calculate an association measure which would take magnitude into account, and this would be used in the plot instead of count, and then run a cluster analysis and plot, make facet by cluster.